# Representing array of objects with different types in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using REST adapter with latest ember-data and latest Ember.js (RC5)

I have model `Module` with following mapping:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    header: DS.attr('string')
});
```

against the API which returns JSON:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "modules": [{
        "id": "123456",
        "type": "video",
        "url": "http://some.where.com/video.mp4"
    }, {
        "id": "123457",
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..."
    }, {
        "id": "123458",
        "type": "feedback",
        "header": "Indtast noget feedback til os."
    }]
}
```

- As you can see modules have different types.
- There can be many objects with the same type.
- Modules are objects in array because order is important.

The issue I'm having is **how to represent them in template?** I need to create different views for each of them, but there is no such a thing in handlebars like if `type === video then` (only boolean if which make me worries I'm tying to solve problem from the wrong way) render different view:

```
if type === video
{{view moduleVideo}}

if type === text
{{view moduleText}}

if type === feedback
{{view moduleFeedback}}
```

How to render different views for different types? Or is there a more Ember.js way to design such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogue of the switch-type structure you have above is to define identifying properties on your model.

```
App.Module = DS.Model.extend({

    // ...

    isVideo: function() {
        return this.get('type') === 'video';
    }.property('type'),

    isText: function() {
        return this.get('type') === 'text';
    }.property('text'),

    // ...

});
```

In your template, you now have booleans:

```
{{#if isVideo}}
    {{view moduleVideo}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isText}}
    {{view moduleText}}
{{/if}}
```

This works, but is undesirable for two reasons:

1. You need a new computed property for every type.
2. You end up with a giant list of conditionals in your template.

One way around this might be to make a Handlebars helper to replace `{{render}}` that uses the type of the model to select a suitable controller/view/template based on naming conventions.

An alternative would be to give your model a computed property that renders its output and then use a triple-handlebars binding to dump it into your template. You could then override the output property differently for different sub-classes. This would work well with Ember Data's polymorphism.

**Edit:**

[Here's a jsfiddle of what I was trying to describe above](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/Yu4VN/).

Comment: I have only 3 types, so it's fine for now. The issue is that when I tested your solution only last module is displayed.. In your code above would render `moduleText` view but not `moduleVideo` view, any idea why? When I delete `moduleText` then `moduleVideo` renders.

Comment: Actually I think your solution can't work. Observer is set on `type` and on each of loop iteration over the Model it updates `isText` and `isVideo` properties, so after last loop iteration only last one is `true` and thanks to `{{#if` in handlebars all previos are removed from the DOM...

Comment: OK, I found simplest solution! In template just use `{{#if video}}` or `{{#if text}}` since video module has no text property :- )

Comment: I added a jsfiddle of what I proposed above. The advantage of using dedicated properties is that you could have two different kinds of videos that render differently. If that's not the case, then your solution is much quicker.